# Cloud function trigger for specific filename or pattern in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

Lets say I upload `folder/blah.json` to a cloud storage bucket in firebase. How would I trigger a cloud function only when a file `folder/blah.json` is uploaded?

Is this possible or do I need to check the filename in the function and early-out it it doesn't match what I'm looking for?

The reason I ask is that a lot of stuff will be uploaded to the bucket, and it seems inefficient (and costly) for the function to trigger every time.

Bonus points if someone knows how to do this with a wildcard path `*/blah.json`.

Comment: There currently is no way to have a Cloud Function trigger for only specific files. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404270/is-it-possible-to-scope-firebase-functions-to-a-folder-inside-a-storage-bucket/45405350#45405350

Comment: Thanks for finding that answer. Was not able to find with a search.