# Firebase (single) document trigger stopped working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

As storage triggers are bucket-wide, I'm using a firestore trigger to watch changes in the "UploadTriggers/" path where the docId labels each target file (this is a small static list) and the storage_path entry in that doc points to where I've updoaded the file.

This worked great right of of the gate, but it has just stopped working. (I tried reducing the whole fn to a single console.log, but still nothing.)

There is no log output at all, and no indication of failure - just nothing.
I've tried re-deploying the fn's (with and w/o a rename) to no avail.

Any ideas?

```
export const myFn = functions.firestore
                    .document('UploadTriggers/MyFile.csv')
                    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {

        const path = changed.after.data().storage_path;
        console.log("csv updated:", path);
        // ...load stream from path and do neat things...
```

Comment: I'm confused because your question says you're writing a Cloud Storage trigger on a bucket, but your code shows a Firestore trigger.  These two cloud products are completely different.  You can't write a Firestore trigger that responds to Cloud Storage bucket updates.  I doubt that your shown trigger ever fired at all to Cloud Storage updates.  Please review the documentation for [Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) and [Cloud Storage triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events).  They are definitely not the same.

Comment: I am writing a firebase trigger to notify me of certain storage changes -- so after I upload to storage, I modify the db to cause this trigger.  You can't do per-path storage triggers because you can only narrow down the storage trigger by the entire bucket, and I don't want my fn to run on every storage change in the bucket.

Comment: How are you triggering this function? Can you show the code for that in your question?

Comment: The explanation you gave in the comment requires a lot more explanation in terms of code and overall data flow through your system. Please edit the question to completely explain how this is supposed to work, especially how you expect this trigger to get executed, as Frank says.

Comment: How am I triggering the fn? It's a db trigger - so it could be from user SDK, admin SDK, CLI or by manually fiddling the db from the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was working fine -- it was a combination of the fn taking much longer to execute than expected (something in centralus?) and the rather bizarre way that logs are presented in the firebase dashboard -- it seems to present some random subset of the logs at any given moment.

Comment: I found another example of someone doing something similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404270/is-it-possible-to-scope-firebase-functions-to-a-folder-inside-a-storage-bucket